# Why bit shift left on system call bits?

Tags: c, kernel, minix

In [kernel/ipc.h](https://github.com/danielbarter/minix_book/blob/minix_book/kernel/ipc.h) Tanenbaum defines the system call bits as:

```
/* System call numbers that are passed when trapping to the kernel. The 
 * numbers are carefully defined so that it can easily be seen (based on 
 * the bits that are on) which checks should be done in sys_call().
 */
#define SEND           1    /* 0 0 0 1 : blocking send */
#define RECEIVE        2    /* 0 0 1 0 : blocking receive */
#define SENDREC        3    /* 0 0 1 1 : SEND + RECEIVE */
#define NOTIFY         4    /* 0 1 0 0 : nonblocking notify */
#define ECHO           8    /* 1 0 0 0 : echo a message */
```

but then in [kernel/table.c](https://github.com/danielbarter/minix_book/blob/minix_book/kernel/table.c) the system call bits are defined as:

```
/* Define system call traps for the various process types. These call masks
 * determine what system call traps a process is allowed to make.
 */
#define TSK_T   (1 << RECEIVE)                   /* clock and system */
#define SRV_T   (~0)                             /* system services */
#define USR_T   ((1 << SENDREC) | (1 << ECHO))   /* user processes */
```

**Why is everything bit shifted over to the left?** `1 << RECEIVE` would be **0100** instead of **0010**. Doesn't that mean that the clock and system tasks can NOTIFY but not RECEIVE?

Comment: The ip.h names are the bit position, the table values are the bit mask

Answer (score 2):

The values formed in the code you show from `kernel/table.c` are not the values of the code numbers for system calls. They are bit masks for the system calls.

Bit masks are commonly used to implement sets. Suppose we have three objects, such as an apple, a banana, and a cherry, and we wish to record whether some set X does or does not contain an apple, does or does not contain a banana, and does or does not contain a cherry.

We can do this by assigning the bit at position 0 (value 1) to represent an apple, the bit at position 1 (value 2) to represent a banana, and the bit at position 2 (value 4) to represent a cherry. Then whether any set X does or does not contain these items can be represented by a number which does or does not have the corresponding bits set. For example, the number 5 has bits at positions 0 and 2 set, so it represents a set that contains an apple and a cherry but not a banana.

The code in `kernel/table.c` assigns bits in a bit mask so that the system call with code *i* is represented by the bit at position *i*. Thus, the value of the bit in the bit mask for the system call with code *i* has value `1 << i`.

Here is a table showing the values of the call codes and the values of their bit masks:

```
    Call Name    Code Number    Bit Mask
    SEND         1              2
    RECEIVE      2              4
    SENDREC      3              8
    NOTIFY       4              16
    ECHO         8              256
```

The way these are used is that, to represent a set containing several calls, the bit mask values for those calls are added together (or, equivalent, combined with a bitwise OR operation). So the set containing `SEND`, `RECEIVE`, and `SENDREC` is represented by 2+4+8 = 14.

So `1 << SENDREC` is the value of the bit that represents `SENDREC` in the mask, and `1 << ECHO` is the value of the bit that represents `ECHO` in the mask. The OR of these values, `1 << SENDREC | 1 << ECHO`, is a bit mask that includes `SENDREC` and `ECHO` but does not include `SEND` or the other codes.

Some operations on bit masks are:

- If `i` is the number of an item, `1<<i` is the value of the bit that represents it in the set.
- To add one item `i` to a set `X`, OR the bit into the set, with `X |= 1<<i`.
- To take the union of two sets `X` and `Y`, OR them, with `X | Y`.
- To take the intersection of two sets `X` and `Y`, AND them, with `X & Y`.

Comment: Wouldn't it then be `x << i` where `x` is either 0 or 1?

Comment: Oh! I think I get it! You take `1 << i` and AND it with some value and that results in `x << i`, correct?

Comment: @JakeKing: I added some examples of simple operations on bit masks.

Comment: Wait, so couldn't the bitmask just be done with `value & RECEIVE` and `(value & ECHO) | (value & SENDREC)`?

Comment: @JakeKing: What is `value`? If it is just a 0 or 1 for on or off, then, no, `value & RECEIVE` is not what you want. `value & RECEIVE` does not shift the bit to the desired location. Experiment with writing some code that shifts bits and ANDs and ORs them (and displays the results in hexadecimal or binary).

Comment: But isn't `SENDREC` supposed to be 0011b? That's setting on two bits instead of one. `1 << SENDREC` would mask a value of only a single bit. Also aren't all of the bits supposed to fit in a half-byte?

Comment: @JakeKing: A bit mask does **not** use the values of codes. A code number for **one** system call is simply a number, such as the codes 1, 2, 3, 4, or 8 defined in `kernel/ipc.h`. A **bit mask** is a set of bits, where each bit represents one item. Typically, the bits representing an integer are numbered 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and so on, where bit 0 represents value 1, bit 1 represents value 2, bit 2 represents value 4, bit 3 represents value 8, and so on. To form a bit mask from the call codes, each call code `C` is assigned to the bit in position `C`, meaning the bit with value `1<<C`.

Comment: @JakeKing: If a bit mask has bits 3 and 8 set, it means that codes 3 and 8 are allowed, meaning that `SENDREC` and `ECHO` are allowed. The bit mask with bits 3 and 8 set is the bit mask formed by adding the values 2^3 and 2^8, which is 8 + 256 = 264.